# Add curved path on left / right arrow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, curve, ellipse, arrow-keys

```
if(game.pressedKeys[37]) {
        this.ship.x -= this.shipSpeed * dt;
    }
if(game.pressedKeys[39]) {
        this.ship.x += this.shipSpeed * dt;
    }
```

This code works very well. But I want, scroll path be curved. A kind of like this:

[image]

What should be my solution? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can the curve be parabolic?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz yes, it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always know the x position of your ship. Create a function that takes an `x` position and returns a `y`.

The curve you have could be represented by the parabolic function `y=a(x-s)^2+b` where `a` is the vertical stretch, `s` is the sideways shift, and `b` is the vertical shift.

Here I created such a function that works for a screen width of 500, and the ship goes up to a max of 150

[image]

```
function parabolic(x) {
    return Math.pow((((1/20.412415)*x)-12.24745),2)+150;
}
//I am using ugly numbers, however you can have a variable `w` for the screen width
```

Here is a working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v7va0L9/) (Click on the canvas for keyboard to work)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which===37) {
    ship.x--;
  } else if(e.which===39) {
    ship.x++;
  }
  ship.y = parabolic(ship.x);
  update();
})
```